# Is there a more proper way to denote the question-and-answer literature, as title of academic work?

Tags: british-english, literary-english, academia

In a context of an academic publication addressing readers favoring British English, what would be the better way to denote the "Questions and Answers" genre?

I am looking for a more specialised way of addressing that literary genre, as a title or subtitle of an academic work in the humanities.

To clarify, using as comparison the nuance between Discourse/Talk: by perusing the bibliography related to Buddhist Studies, it seems to me it is preferred to use titles like, "The discourses of the Buddha" instead of "The talks of the Buddha".

In that vein, I was wondering if such more precise distinction exists for the genre "Questions and Answers" as well.

Is there a more proper way to denote the question-and-answer literature, as title of academic work?

[This question has been edited for clarity, thanks to the comments below.]

Comment: Better or more proper in what way/s?

Comment: In the way "Discourses" could feel more scholarly that "Talks".

Comment: What is wrong with *Questions and Answers*?

Comment: Query and Response?

Comment: @Drew: Nothing wrong of course. I was just wondering if there was a more "technical" way of addressing that literary genre. Using as comparison the genre Discourse/Talk, it seems to me it is preferred to say, for example, "The discourses of the Buddha", instead of "The talks of the Buddha". In that vein, I was wondering if such a more precise distinction exists for "Questions and Answers", as well.

Comment: @Jim: I am not sure, that sounds more like a synonym that a more precise literary term?

Comment: *it is preferred to say*: By whom? Why? I guess your context is academic publication.  *Talks* and *questions and answers* are not inappropriate terms for academic publication, IMO. Contrary to popular belief, using long, latinate words does **not** make something more scholarly.

Comment: @Drew: Thank you, latinisms are seldom the right choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "Questions and Answers" you mean "responses by someone to a series of questions put to him or her by a single questioner," then one common term you might use is ***interview***, and the genre comparable to "Discourses" might be "Interviews." A somewhat stiffer (and broader) term that may be applied to a reported conversation—whether conducted in Q&A format or not—is "colloquy," which Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) defines as follows:

> **colloquy** *n* **1 :** CONVERSATION, DIALOGUE **2 :** a high-level serious discussion : CONFERENCE

But there is another type of academic proceeding called a *colloquium* that involves (according to the same dictionary) "a usu. academic meeting at which specialists deliver addresses on a topic or on related topics and then answer questions relating to them"—so using *colloquy* in place of *interview* might just confuse the issue.

But perhaps you have something else in mind when you use the term "Questions and Answers"— such as a fact sheet in question-and-answer form—also known as a "Frequently Asked Questions" page. Without having a more precise understanding of what you mean by the term, I can't tell whether I'm responding to your underlying question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The specialised idiom I was looking for is about questions put to one individual by different questioners, in the course of a public or private conference, or function.

Comment: In that case, I don't think that _Interviews_ works especially well. Maybe _Colloquium_ (or _Colloquia_ plural) would work, if you include the address part of the program as well as the Q&A segment. If only the Q&A segment of the event is to be reported, though, your options may be rather limited.

Comment: Thank you, that's quite useful. A noted example is `The Colloquies of Erasmus`. It might be useful to add this to the main answer. Thank you once again.